# SQL query with equal limits for BETWEEN

Tags: sql, performance, db2

Suppose I have a query,

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE col1 BETWEEN  111 AND 111;
```

Or a query

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE col1=111;
```

Is there any difference in performance between the two?

The table can be large, and is queried many times.

EDIT: The query can have upto 15 fields in the WHERE clause like col1. Also, the columns are always a part of the primary key.

Comment: What is the table index column ?

Comment: Second query perhaps slightly faster. Measurable or not?

Comment: I wouldn't expect much difference - if any. But why use `BETWEEN` when you can use `=`?

Comment: The second one should be potentially more performant, but at a query this simple, the engine should be smart enough to transform the first one into the second one (actually, to figure out they're one and the same). @ypercubeᵀᴹ - I'm guessing it's a parametrised query so sometimes it ends up having `BETWEEN 111 AND 111`.

Comment: There isnt any index as far as I know. And the column is part of the key.
The reason is that the value may or may not be equal. Currently we use different queries for either case( equal or not equal). I was wondering if it was really necessary. The query can have upto 15 such columns, but always part of the key.

Comment: @MK_ right. Also, adding an index on `(col)` will have much more performance gains than the change from BETWEEN to =.

Comment: @vivek if the query can have up to 15 BETWEEN conditions (even just 2), then it's a totally different question.

Comment: The only objective answer will be based on comparing actual query plans; everything else is just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously doubt that there would be any discernible difference in the two queries as written.  There are really two cases:

- No index on `col1`.  Both would do a full table scan.  The second would (in all likelihood) do two comparisons rather than one for the `between`.  That should not be noticeable.
- Index on `col1`.  Both would use the index.

The more interesting case is:

```
 WHERE col1 BETWEEN 111 AND 111 AND col2 > 0
 WHERE col1 = 111 AND col2 > 0
```

The second can make full use of an index on `(col1, col2)`.  The second *probably* would not.  It is possible that DB2 does detect this particular situation where the `between` limits are the same.  Normally, `between` is treated like an inequality for determining indexes.